# QGIS - Select by expression - How to select the smallest ploygon with conditions

Tags: expression, qgis

I have a very odd dataset of polygons that looks like this :

| id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

When the id and the text is the same, I would like to select the smallest polygon thanks to an expression.

I tried an expression with IF but it didn't work

Comment: Should I ask this question in Geographic Information System (https://gis.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

This expression might work (using newlines is optional):

```
$area = aggregate( 'test',
'min',
$area, 
count(1, "id" || '_' || "text") > 1 
  and "id" = attribute(@parent, 'id') 
  and "text" = attribute(@parent, 'text')
)
```

Explanation:

- Replace table name "test" (once) and field names "id" and "text" (each three times) with your own
- the area of the geometry in the current record is checked with an aggregate
- the first parameter of the aggregate function is the layer name from which to collect data, which is the current layer "test" itself
- the aggregate is a "min" (select the minimum)
- the expression from which the minimum should be calculated is the area of the geometry in the referred table (specified as the first parameter in the aggregate function)
- that referred table is filtered, in three parts:
- [1] the concatenation of fields "id" and "text" should have duplicates: the count must yield a number greater than 1
- [2] field "id" in the referred table should be identical to field "id" in the current record (where the current table record is accessed with @parent)
- [3] field "text" in the referred table should be identical to field "id" in the current record

If, however, the expression should select *all* non-duplicated features *plus* only the smallest geometry feature from duplicated features, then remove the 'count' filter.